# WPF - Get specific value from List<class>

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, database, list

so i have `List<data> dataList` that includes `int idx, string tag, string value` with this code :

```
List<data> dataList = new List<data>();
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["info"].Rows)
{
    dataList.Add(new data() { idx = (int)row["idx"], tag = (string)row["tag"], value = (string)row["value"] });
}
```

I want to get specific value from idx,tag,value from specific index.
For example, if there is 3 rows from idx,tag,value i want to put all the value in textbox-es so i create 9 textbox-es for each value. I tried this code but i only got the last row values. And i realise that my code here is to get all value and only print the last one.

```
foreach (data item in dataList)
{
    idx1.Text = item.idx.ToString();
    tag1.Text = item.tag.ToString();
    value1.Text = item.value.ToString();
}
```

But i realise that my code here is to get all value and only print the last one. How can i fill all my textbox with all value in dataList?

Comment: How many textboxes you have ?? Your question is not very clear? Please rephrase it to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I tried it myself and `dataList[i].idx.ToString()` is my answer for it.
so i just need to make a loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < idxBox.Count; i++)
{
    idxBox[i].Text = dataList[i].idx.ToString();
    tagBox[i].Text = dataList[i].tag;
    valueBox[i].Text = dataList[i].value;
}
```

but before that i create 3 List for idx,tag and value

```
List<TextBox> idxBox = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> tagBox = new List<TextBox>();
List<TextBox> valueBox = new List<TextBox>();
```

and add the textbox names in it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have a dynamic amount of DataRows. Creating a static amount of TextBoxes to hold their values (as you did with `idx1`, `tag1` and `value1`) is not the best way to tackle your problem.

A `ListView` can hold a dynamic amount of rows, so it is much better suited for your case.

You can define it like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Idx" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding idx}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Tag" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tag}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And add items like this:

```
foreach (data item in dataList)
{
    listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: yes thanks for your answer and suggestion for trying GridView, but its different case.